# Finding nearest location Google Places API

Tags: google-places-api

I have a project that uses Google places to search for a specific type of business using a keyword search, centered on my user's current location. For example suppose I'm trying to find "Pink Bunny Rabbits" closest to my users.

In some cases, my user is located in a place where none of my specific types of businesses are withing the Google Places API maximum search radius (20KM, IIRC). "No Pink Bunny Rabbits close to you"

Is there some method that will search for the nearest matching business, even if it's outside the initial max search range?
"Closest Pink Bunny Rabbit:  30 miles away in Sometown,IA"

Is Google Places is the correct API to use for this secondary search.

What fallback services can I use to find the "Pink Bunny Rabbit" store closest to my user?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there is a scope of making a place search with larger radius. `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere`. 
The current search covers a circle with 500 meter around the latitude and longitude provided in search url. The maximum value for that is 50000. Unfortunately [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/search) does not sort the result according to user's current location. You need to manually calculate the distance in between the location of the place from search result and your current location.

```
// Calculating the distance
float deltaLat = (currentLocation.lat - place.lat);
float deltaLng = (currentLocation.lng - place.lng);
float distanceInDegree = sqrtf(deltaLat * deltaLat + deltaLng * deltaLng);
float distanceInMeter = distanceInDegree * 4000;
printf("distanceInMeter = %f",distanceInMeter);
```

Find out the place with minimum distance.